# PHP. Проверить окончание url на соответствие

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, уважаемое сообщество!
Нужно в независимости от наличия www в url, а также HTTP или HTTPS, проверить окончание url на соответствие ( в данном случае это: users/[любое число] ; users/[любое число ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО ДОЛЖНО ВПЕРЕДИ][любые символы]), и выполнить одно действие. В противном случае выполняется другое действие.

При этом окончание url такого вида проверку на соответствие уже не проходят:
users/ [любое число] / [любые символы]
users/[любое число][любые символы] / [любые символы]

Уточнение: в url жестко заданна только эта часть (users). Остальное, включая поддомен(если имеется)\домен\доменная зона (рф\ru\com...) и оставшаяся часть url должны\могут быть любыми.

Весь вчерашний вечер и сегодняшние пол дня рыскаю по интернету, но похожего решения именно для окончания url не нашел.

Надеюсь суть вопроса описал достаточно ясно.
Спасибо за внимание! Буду признателен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитывая последнее уточнение, как-то так:

```
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
if (preg_match('|users/[0-9]+$|',$parsed_url['path'])) {
    // делаете то что вам нужно
}
```

[parse_url (php.net)](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php)

Наверняка можно было бы решить это дело и чисто регулярным выражением, но я предпочитаю всё же встроенные функции, если они есть (обычно они делают то, для чего предназначены, очень хорошо и быстро).

Comment: Извиняюсь. Мне следовало сразу уточнить что в url жестко заданна только эта часть (users). Остальное, включая поддомен(если имеется)\домен\доменная зона (рф\ru\com...) и оставшаяся часть url должны\могут быть любыми.

Comment: У вас это и написано в задаче, в и ответе учтено это. Либо Вы пишете одно, а хотите сказать совершенно другое.

Comment: Меня смущает вот эта часть nezavisimo.chto/tut/napisano/. Ведь при заливке файлов на другой домен придется все изменять вручную на drugoy-domen.chto/tut/napisano/. И глубина ссылки может изменяться, например nezavisimo.chto/users/234234. Мне нужно, чтобы это все учитывалось.

Comment: Строчки `$a = ...` приведены для примера, какие данные подставляются, в комментарии написано что выведется. Вы читали инфу по [функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)?

Comment: Спасибо, почти идеально, но вот окончание url такого вида:  users/1?text=92&one=176 , также должно проходить проверку на соответствие.